# Wordpress - First check page.php in plugin

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is it possible to make WordPress look at plugin directory first and if the system finds that page, for example, page.php, archive.php, single.php... show layout from plugin files and don't look at theme files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely! Take a look at the [`single_template`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/single_template) and [`archive_template`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/archive_template) filters. They're relatively straight forward to use:

```
function get_custom_post_type_template($single_template) {
     global $post;

     if ($post->post_type == 'my_post_type') {
          $single_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/post-type-template.php';
     }
     return $single_template;
}
add_filter( 'single_template', 'get_custom_post_type_template' );
```

There's also [This Section](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/single_template#Add_single-.7Bpost_type.7D-.7Bslug.7D.php_to_Template_Hierarchy) on effectively adding `single-post_type.php` to the Template Hierarchy, but I prefer a slightly modified version that is IMO easier to read:

```
add_filter( 'single_template', 'my_single_templates' );
function my_single_templates( $single_template ){
    global $post;

    $file = '/my/path/to/templates/dir/'. $post->post_type .'/single-'. $post->post_type .'php';

    if( file_exists( $file ) )
        $single_template = $file;

    return $single_template;
}
```